# Weird behaviour with system calls in C

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

My goal is to turn a `txt` file into a string in `c`.
This is my code currently:

I get the path of two files as arguments. I then do:

```
char* path1 = argv[1];
char* path2 = argv[2];
fpath1 = open(path1,O_RDONLY);
fpath2 = open(path2,O_RDONLY);


int length = lseek(fpath1, 0, SEEK_END);
char string1[length];
lseek(fpath1, 0, SEEK_SET);
read(fpath1, string1, length);

int length2 = lseek(fpath2, 0, SEEK_END);
char string2[length2];
lseek(fpath2, 0, SEEK_SET);
read(fpath2, string2, length2);
```

Note that I can't use the `stdio.h` library but the only system calls functions.

The weird behavior is when debugging:
When I do `char string1[length];` the first time it creates a string with a random length, despite the length int being correct.

Only after I'm done with both strings, the debug show me the content of string1 and `string2`, but weirdly the `string1` is truncated in the middle, and its size is equal to that of `string2`, I'm not sure why.

I would rather not allocate memory dynamically.

Any idea?

Comment: Please edit your answer to include a [mre] (emphasis on reproducible) including the command you use to compile and run the program. If this even compiles, you will have multiple warnings shown by the compiler. Add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and recompile and look at the warnings. `lseek` and `read` surely do not take a path as first argument, if that's what you are passing.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html <- "attempts to read up to"  "It is not an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes requested" -- `read` does this, you should be calling it in a loop until you get everything you wanted. Also, you should have error handling.

Comment: Most C string functions expect null-terminated strings, but `read` does not null-terminate.  (If it did, it would overrun your buffer anyway.)   Conversely, the file might contain null characters which would terminate the string prematurely.  Generally, you can't expect to use string functions on binary data read from files; you have to manage lengths yourself instead.

Comment: @NateEldredge @dratenik I know, this is why I get the length of the file first and then read up to that length. The length int is correct, is different between `path1` and `path2` accordingly. It seems like the `string1`changes after I have read the `string2`

Comment: You have absolutely zero checking of return values for errors or even how many bytes were read.  You have not demonstrated that the file contents are text that can be treated as a C string.  And you have not paid heed to the comments that note that `read()` does not properly terminate data so the it can be treated as a string.  Nor have you provided any space for any terminating `'\0'` character - if your `read()` call does read all the contents of the file, and if those contents are in fact text, there's no string because the data isn't properly terminated.

Comment: The size of an array on the stack must be a constant.

Comment: @user2233706: True in C++, not true in C, which has "variable-length array" feature

Answer (score 0):

Almost every single line is a potential issue in your program. The most important things to notice are that:

1. You never check the return value of any of the functions you call. You always should, as almost all syscalls and library functions can fail in different ways.
2. You are calling `read` only once, but `read` is not guaranteed to read all the required data in a single call. You should call it in a loop until you have read all the data you need (or until an error occurs).
3. Allocating an array the entire size of the file on the stack with `char string1[length]` does not make much sense and can cause your program to crash for not having enough space on the stack. Use `malloc()` instead. If you do not want to allocate with `malloc`, well, I hope your file is small enough. Alternatively, you could simply [`mmap()`](https://manned.org/mmap.2) the entire file and be done with it. *Note that* declaring a variable-length array on the stack only works from C99.
4. You are not NUL-terminating your strings with `'\0'`.

Kepp in mind, the easiest way to prevent this kind of problems is to always read the manual:

- [`man 2 open`](https://manned.org/open.2)
- [`man 2 read`](https://manned.org/read.2)
- [`man 2 lseek`](https://manned.org/lseek.2)
- [`man 2 mmap`](https://manned.org/mmap.2)

To fix 1, simply check the return values of *all* functions. Also, checking `argc` before accessing `argv` wouldn't hurt.

```c
if (argc < 3) {
    fputs("Not enough arguments, usage: ./prog PATH1 PATH2\n", stderr);
    return 1;
}

// ...

fpath1 = open(path1,O_RDONLY);
if (fpath1 == -1) {
    perror("open failed");
    return 1;   
}

// note that lseek returns off_t, not int
off_t length = lseek(fpath1, 0, SEEK_END);
if (length == (off_t)-1) {
    perror("lseek (SEEK_END) failed");
    return 1;
}

// ...

if (lseek(fpath1, 0, SEEK_SET) == (off_t)-1) {
    perror("lseek (SEEK_SET) failed");
    return 1;
}

if (read(fpath1, string1, length) == -1) {
    perror("read failed");
    return 1;
}
```

To fix 2, use a loop when reading. And to fix 4, terminate the string correctly. This also means allocating 1 more character for the terminator (`length + 1` instead of `length`). Finally, to also fix 3, you can use `malloc()` to dynamically allocate the string.

```c
char *string1;

// Dynamically allocate the string instead of declaring
// a huge array on the stack. Alternatively directly mmap
// the file after opening.

string1 = malloc(length + 1);
if (string1 == NULL) {
    perror("malloc failed");
    return 1;
}

ssize_t res;
ssize_t n = 0;

while (n < length) {
    res = read(fpath1, string1 + n, length - n);
    if (res == 0) {
        // read reached end of file earlier than expected
        // do something if you want to handle this case
    } else if (res == -1) {
        perror("read failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    n += res;
}

// correctly terminate the string
string1[n] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would rather not allocate memory dynamically.

Then I do not understand the problem. By *turn a txt file into a string*, I would have thought you meant *populate a character array from a file, terminated with an ASCII NUL*.  What do you mean, if not that?

Unless you know how big the file is at compile time, or are willing to set a hard-coded maximum size, you *must* use dynamic memory in some form, if the data are to be brought into memory.

Only half-kidding: my solution, since your question isn't very clearly stated, would be this:

- open the file
- seek to the end
- call **mmap**(2)

You now have a string in memory that is the exact image of the text file.  You know exactly how long it is, but it might not have a NUL terminator.  mmap has a private mode that allows the memory to be updated and not passed to the file, so in you could tack on the NUL in memory if you want to.